# Why does returning a std::optional sometimes move and sometimes copy?

Tags: c++, c++17, return-value-optimization

See the below example of returning an optional of `UserName` - a movable/copyable class.

```
std::optional<UserName> CreateUser()
{
   UserName u;
   return {u}; // this one will cause a copy of UserName
   return u;   // this one moves UserName
}


int main()
{
   auto d = CreateUser();
}
```

Why does `return {u}` cause a copy and `return u` a move?

Here's the related coliru sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf853750b38d110

Another case (thanks to the comment from @Slava):

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo() 
{ 
    std::unique_ptr<int> p; 
    return {p};  // uses copy of unique_ptr and so it breaks...
}
```

Comment: You forgot to remove unrelated to question operator new and delete in the example.

Comment: @Slava deleted the delete/new overloads

Comment: Simpler code to reproduce: `std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    return {p};
}`

Comment: thanks @Slava - I've updated the question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because returning a **name** of an object with automatic storage duration is treated as returning an rvalue of the object. Note this works only if the expression in the return statement is a (possibly parenthesized, not including braces) name, like `return u;` or `return (u);`, so `return {u};` works as usual, i.e. the copy constructor is invoked.

Related part in the standard [[class.copy.elision]/3](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3):

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a return statement ([stmt.return]) is a **(possibly parenthesized) id-expression** that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or
> - ...
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

Comment: I don't understand why return{u} didn't get the same treatment as the others, I mean it's a return statement, the variable "u" is going out of scope, is there a case where a COPY should be used?

Comment: @watashiSHUN I don't know. It's the rule. I think only the committee who made this rule knows the reason.

Answer (score 5):

This is a kind of *braced-init-list*. [[dcl.init.list]/1.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#1.3)

To be even more specific, it is an ***"*** *expr-or-braced-init-list* [[dcl.init]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:expr-or-braced-init-list)

of a *return statement* ***"*** [[stmt.return]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2)

> A return statement with any other operand shall be used only in a
> function whose return type is not cv void; the return statement
> initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the
> (explicit or implicit) function call by **copy-initialization** from the
> **operand**.

From this point, let me qoutes xskxzr's answer that mention [[class.copy.elision]/3](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3)

> In the following **copy-initialization contexts**, a **move operation** might be used **instead** of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a return statement ([stmt.return]) is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or

---

In normal human words, the reason that copy is called instead of move because braced-init-list call `u` that happened to be lvalue.

So, you may wanna know if *braced-init-list* call `u` that is *rvalue* ...

```
return {std::move(u)};
```

Well, `u` is moved to a new rvalue of `UserName` and copy elision works right after.

So this takes one move as in

```
return u;
```

[godbolt.org/g/b6stLr](https://godbolt.org/g/b6stLr)

[wandbox.org/permlink/7u1cPc0TG9gqToZD](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7u1cPc0TG9gqToZD)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct UserName
{
  int x;
  UserName() : x(0) {};
  UserName(const UserName& other) : x(other.x) { std::cout << "copy " << x << "\n"; };
  UserName(UserName&& other)      : x(other.x) { std::cout << "move "  << x << "\n"; };
};

std::optional<UserName> CreateUser()
{
  UserName u;
  return u;   // this one moves UserName
}

std::optional<UserName> CreateUser_listinit()
{
  UserName u;
  auto whatever{u};
  return whatever;
}

std::optional<UserName> CreateUser_listinit_with_copy_elision()
{
  UserName u;
  return {u};
}

std::optional<UserName> CreateUser_move_listinit_with_copy_elision()
{
  UserName u;
  return {std::move(u)};
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "CreateUser() :\n";
  [[maybe_unused]] auto d = CreateUser();

  std::cout << "\nCreateUser_listinit() :\n";
  [[maybe_unused]] auto e = CreateUser_listinit();

  std::cout << "\nCreateUser_listinit_with_copy_elision() :\n";
  [[maybe_unused]] auto f = CreateUser_listinit_with_copy_elision();

  std::cout << "\nCreateUser_move_listinit_with_copy_elision() :\n";
  [[maybe_unused]] auto g = CreateUser_move_listinit_with_copy_elision();
}
```

print

```
CreateUser() :
move 0

CreateUser_listinit() :
copy 0
move 0

CreateUser_listinit_with_copy_elision() :
copy 0

CreateUser_move_listinit_with_copy_elision() :
move 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> return { *arg1, arg2, ...* } ;

is **[copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)**. the (return) object is initialized from the initializer list by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization

Comment: but `return u;` is also a copy initialization, as mentioned [copy initialization - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Comment: @fen *copy* initialization is not the same as *copy list* initialization

Comment: This doesn't actually. answer the question. Yes, `return {u};` is copy-list-initialization. True. However, why does that copy while the other one moves?